# Not getting the desired output after MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb

Requirement is to fetch user details which matches the input search(name or email) by the logged in user.

Currently I am able to fetch the unique users related to the logged in user but not able to query by using the user inputs.

This is my client-side API call:

```
const handleSearch = async () => {
    if (!search) {
        toast({
            title: 'Please enter name or email',
            status: 'error',
            duration: 5000,
            isClosable: true,
            position: 'top',
        });
        return;
    }
    try {
        setloading(true);
        const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` },
        };
        console.log(typeof search);
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/chat?search=${search}`, config);

        console.log(data);

        setsearchResults(data);

        setloading(false);
    } catch (error) {
        toast({
            title: 'Error occurred',
            description: 'Failed to load the search results',
            status: 'error',
            duration: 5000,
            isClosable: true,
            position: 'top',
        });
        setloading(false);
    }
};
```

Here's my API handler:

```
const fetchChats = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log('inside fetch chats');
    console.log(typeof req.query.search);
    const keyword = req.query.search
        ? {
                $or: [
                    { name: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
                    { email: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
                ],
          }
        : {};
    console.log('keyword : ', { ...keyword });
    try {
        const currentUserChats = await Chat.find({
            users: req.user._id,
            // ...keyword,
        });
        console.log(currentUserChats, "current user's chats");
        const participantIds = currentUserChats.reduce((ids, chat) => {
            chat.users.forEach((userId) => {
                if (
                    userId.toString() !== req.user._id.toString() &&
                    !ids.includes(userId.toString())
                ) {
                    ids.push(userId.toString());
                }
            });
            return ids;
        }, []);
        console.log(participantIds, 'retrieved ids');
        const users = await User.find({ _id: { $in: participantIds } }).select(
            '-password'
        );
        res.status(200).send(users);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
});
```

**FYI**: API is being called correctly, `typeof req.search.query` is string, if I remove "...keyword" as in the above image, it works for fetching users without the query entered by user.

Now I want to filter the users on the basis of name or email entered by user.

Comment: Please [paste code instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/21972629). Are you trying to use spread syntax `...keyword` in the `Chat.find()` method?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but that is not giving me the expected results.

Comment: No it won't. Spread syntax unpacks an array and 'spreads them', objects aren't iterable. Are you trying to find `Chats` that match `users: req.user._id` *AND* the  `keyword` conditions or just one or the other?

Comment: oh is it, I am trying to find the users who already have a chat with the currently logged-in user (here, `req.user` is currently logged-in user), and from that list, I want to filter based on a search query entered by the user (i.e. name or email)

Comment: OK. I've provided a solution that will hopefully help but not sure if there is any point in searching for just `users: req.user._id` if `req.query.search` is empty but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: `{
  users: new ObjectId('65624f533a3ddb9ef5ed4e8e'),
  '$or': [ { name: [Object] }, { email: [Object] } ]
}` This is output for `console.log(query);` in the code you gave. But still facing the same issue. As soon as I compile ` $or: [
            { name: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
            { email: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
         ],` all the results just goes away.

Comment: Does it return an empty array `[]`? The `currentUserChats`.

Comment: yes, exactly. Only when I remove that `$or` part it returns me a proper list based on req.user._id. And I already appreciate the efforts you putting in. Thank you for that and yeah I am kinda stuck here with this, I'll try this latest suggestion by you and come back to you, here.

Comment: Happy to help. If you post a sample document where you expect to make a hit then it might be clearer where the problem is.

Comment: I tried passing `const currentUserChats = await Chat.find({
   users: req.user._id,
   $or: [{ name: { $regex: 'm', $options: 'i' } }],
  });` 
the problem seems to be with this line `$or: [{ name: { $regex: 'm', $options: 'i' } }],`,
the moment I comment this out function works but I am just not able to query this.

Comment: It looks fine. Do you have any documents in your database that you know would match. Post one so that I can see.

Comment: Sure, for the current logged in user this should match `{
    "_id": "655e505d5127b77a418199d0",
    "name": "Milli",
    "email": "devanshi@gmail.com",
    "pic": "http://res.cloudinary.com/the3rdeye/image/upload/v1700679771/katnvamqkbjmoffo37fh.jpg",
    "createdAt": "2023-11-22T19:02:53.547Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-11-22T19:02:53.547Z",
    "__v": 0
}`,as you can see name starts with 'm', so it should match.

Comment: I believe the above document is for the User model. But you are querying it on the Chat document? Where do you have your name and email?

Comment: That doesn’t look like a `Chat` document. You are trying to find a hit on `Chat` so paste into the question a `Chat` document that you think would match your query.

Comment: Heyy, @Arun & @jQueeny, these above couple of comments of yours, solved the issue.
It was silly of me but still took a lot of time to notice. 
Now it looks like `const users = await User.find({
   _id: { $in: participantIds },
   $or: [
    { name: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
    { email: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
   ],
  }).select('-password');`

Thanks for all the help @jQueeny

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer useful please consider [marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `req.query.search` is there then this will set the query object to match where `users: req.user._id` **and** either one of your `name` / `email` conditions. But if `req.query.search` is not there then it will just search for `users: req.user._id` on it's own.

```js
const query = req.query.search
    ? {
         users: req.user._id,
         $or: [
            { name: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
            { email: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: 'i' } },
         ],
      }
    : {users: req.user._id};
```

```js
const currentUserChats = await Chat.find(query);
```